# Magento Move skin and media folder to another URL (subdomain)

Tags: magento, subdomain, media, skin

we have booked an own url (domain) for our skin and media datas and we use Magento 1.7.0.2 (pls note: it is NOT a sub-domain. It is a stand alone domain with its one URL)

If we write in the System / Configuration / Web the different URL for the Base Media and Base Skin Folder we have the follow problem:

Magento search the base and skin folder not at skin / default / theme -where it is present. Magento have always a look at skin / base. And as this would be not enough problems Magento shown all slider images and other images very fine if i write the new URL inside there. But product pictures would not be shown.

any ideas?